# Rewrite single directory to append URL Query

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am stuck on a url rewrite which could do with some expert advice.

I am trying to redirect a sub-directory to a variable that would append an incoming query.

Incoming Request
`http://example.com/guest/d/qwerty/?id=1&other=2&someother=three`

Desired Outcome
`http://example.com/guest/d/?id=1&other=2&someother=three&dir=qwerty`

The /qwerty/ directory name will change depending on incoming request each time I would like only that directory to be appended to the URL as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(guest/d)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/?dir=$2 [L,NC,QSA,R=302]
```

Comment: This partially works, thank you, however it also rewrites files. For example - http://example.com/guest/d/file.php rewrites to http://example.com/guest/d/?dir=file.php - this would cause issues for us.